# Setting a website via home server

Tags: php, wamp

I tried Google and it failed.

I want to set up a localhost website from my computer that people from the Internet can access...

I am using Windows Vista (64-bit). I use WAMP but am open to others... I plan on using no-ip.org for DNS.

If anyone knows of a definitive guide.. please let me know -- thanks

Comment: @RageD Looks more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: @Shaz: Comment removed - it has been changed to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are able to setup WAMP and access your webserver using "localhost," you will need your IP. If people cannot access the IP, make sure you allow these daemons to run through Windows Firewall and if you have a router, you may need to do some port forwarding (very simple) or, if this computer is always public access, look into DMZ (demilitarized zone) to remove the computer from the router's firewall.

Answer (score 0):

An easy WAMP solution is using XAMPP which is an all-in-one package.

Step-by-step guide:

http://www.dkszone.net/install-xampp-windows-step-step-guide

Answer (score 0):

You need:
a webserver,know your IP adress.

If dynamic.. Dynamic DNS, this will bind your new routerIP to a domainname

make sure your router allow traffic by the port 80 and you are done!
ppl will access your home server just by setting the dynamicDNS domain.

Answer (score 0):

Key points-

0) To install IIS on vista:  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-install-iis-on-windows-vista/

1) Your cable/dsl company has to open port 80 for you, or else it will not be accessible outside of your house.

2) You're router will have to forward port 80 to the server.  You can find out how to do that here: http://portforward.com/english/routers/port_forwarding/Linksys/BEFSR41/BEFSR41index.htm

3) before picking a dns service, check if your router supports one, it is the easiest way to maintain it.